# Why does it roll the dice even though I say "no" when it asks if I want to do it again?

Tags: python, function

I was writing a Roll the dice game but when I get the question "Would you like to roll the dice again?" and I say "no" it rolls anyway. I'm guessing it has something to do with the `answer` variable. However, I would like it to print "maybe next time" instead. Can you help me? Here's my code:

```
import random

def response():
  if answer == "yes" or answer == "Yes" :
    rolldice()
  else:
    print("Maybe next time!")


def rolldice():
    randomnumb = random.randrange(1,7)
    print("You got number " + str(randomnumb) + "!")
    answer = input("Would you like to roll the dice again? \n ")
    response()


answer = input("Would you like to roll the dice? \n")
response()
```

Comment: Does this even run? `rolldice()` isn't indented as it should be, and I'd imagine the python interpreter should complain about expecting an indented block.

Comment: Just tried- gives `IndentationError: expected an indented block` on line 5 for me.

Comment: It was a mistake in copying the code to the website. I didn't run it like that.

Comment: The problem is that `rolldice` is creating a local variable named `answer`, not reassigning the global variable. If you want to work with global variables this way, you need to declare them with `global answer` at the top of each function body. But a better solution is to not use global variables—pass the values around as arguments and return values when that makes sense, make the functions methods of a class with a `self.answer` when you can’t write them without shared state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. You have to pass answer as argument to the function response:

```
import random

def response(answer):
    if answer == "yes" or answer == "Yes" :
      rolldice()
    else:
      print("Maybe next time!")


def rolldice():
    randomnumb = random.randrange(1,7)
    print("You got number " + str(randomnumb) + "!")
    response(input("Would you like to roll the dice again? \n "))

response(input("Would you like to roll the dice? \n"))
```

Comment: Missing a `)` there, 2nd to last line (with text)